implementation ‘com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0’ Isn't working in Android Studio Code
I'm working on an app which relies on talking to chatgpt (like a chatbot). The only method I know of is using
implementation ‘com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0’
and putting it in build.gradle.
But this always shows up as an error because all the other implementations are like this:
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.firebase.storage)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)

Full build.gradle:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.google.gms.google.services)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.wordmatcher"
    compileSdk = 34


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.wordmatcher"
        minSdk = 30
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.firebase.storage)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)


}

Any help is appreciated!
I've tried importing com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0 but it still gives an error on the word volley.

The documentation covers how to add dependencies to projects like yours that use libs.versions.toml.
